# Como assinar um ficheiro PDF com o Cartão de Cidadão ou Chave Móvel Digital em PHP?

Tags: php

Pessoal tem uma dúvida que há semanas tenho andado a resolver, existe alguma maneira de assinar um documento em PDF com o **Cartão de Cidadão** ou com a **Chave Móvel Digital** em **PHP** ?

Comment: Bem vindo ao **StackOverflow PT** @Rodolfo Melo. Aproveite para fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para melhor perceber como funciona o site. Em relação à sua questão, acho que só com o _software_ específico que o Estado providencia é que é possível fazer tal coisa.